# Difference between active_main and fragment main

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

I don't if this was asked before but I really don't get it I have this code in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

it says `setcontentview` to `activiy_main` but when do something in `fragment_main` it still appears? in the app

Comment: Obviously activity_main has fragment_main  in it.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html                        http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example